# How to click a button within ListView item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ListView like this:

```
<ListView  x:Name="Thumbnails"   HorizontalContentAlignment ="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Padding="0"  Background ="#81AFD3" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="27" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding NumberOfSlides}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ThumbnailsSelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Thumbnails.SelectedIndex, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>


    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource Thumbnail}" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DummyRectangle2}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
         Color="Blue"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

and the item for the list is defined like this:

```
<Grid x:Key="Thumbnail" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DummyRectangle}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DummyRectangle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent" >

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Name="thumbImage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="14" Grid.RowSpan="7" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="/MS_Show_Assets/ImportAssets/Test.jpg"></Image>

    <StackPanel Name="Overlay" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="7" Background="LightBlue" Opacity="0.4"/>


    <Button Name="slide_ON_OFF" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding SlideOnOffCommand}">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="bg">
                    <Image Source="/MS_Show_Assets/ImportAssets/Visible_ON.png"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>

    </Button>

    <Button Name="fadein_ON_OFF" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="bg">
                <Image x:Name ="main_image" Source="/MS_Show_Assets/ImportAssets/Bulletpoint_ON.png"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

and the ViewModel:

```
 public CompositeCommand SlideOnOffCommand { get; set; }

SlideOnOffCommand = new CompositeCommand();
SlideOnOffCommand.RegisterCommand(new DelegateCommand(SlideOnOff));

 private void SlideOnOff()
        {

        }
```

As you can see, the list item contains some buttons. I hooked one of them to a command in ViewModel, but when clicked, the subscribed method is not getting called. How to make these buttons clickable?

Comment: also show your relevant ViewModel portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a `RelativeSource` at your Command-Binding of the Button-Command.

Your command than should look something like:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.ThumbnailsSelectionChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window} }"
```

If the root-Element of your xaml is a UserControl and not a window than the binding should look like:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.ThumbnailsSelectionChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl} }"
```

Comment: Please see my updated code for the VIewModel portion. How do I bind the button to that command?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
<Button Name="slide_ON_OFF" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding DataContext.SlideOnOffCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
```